# How to play audio from a ByteArray? (dosen't have a URL)

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, arrays, inputstream, html5-audio

I am receiving a ByteArray from a web service and i want to be able to play the audio ByteArray in HTML5 audio tag. I was wondering if it's possible since the audio tag needs an URL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="yourphone.voicemail.*"%>
<%@page import="com.verscom.ws.*"%>
<%@page import="com.verscom.methods.*"%>

<body>
    <button onclick="playSound()">Play Me</button>
    <button onclick="pausrSound()">Pause</button>
    <audio id="audio" controls="controls">
        <source id="mainSrc" type="audio/mp3" onplay="playSound()"></source>
    </audio>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

function playSound(){ 
<% 
EndUserPortalWSServiceStub.GetVoiceMailMessageVcomResponse[] getvmMsgResp = new EndUserPortalWSServiceStub.GetVoiceMailMessageVcomResponse[2];
EndUserMethods endUserMethods = new EndUserMethods();
getvmMsgResp = endUserMethods.getVoiceMailList();

%>
audio.src= <%=getvmMsgResp[0].getVmailMessageWAVFile().getDataSource().getInputStream()%>;
audio.play(); }

function pausrSound(){ audio.pause(); }

</script>
```

the following code doesn't work :

audio.src= <%=getvmMsgResp[0].getVmailMessageWAVFile().getDataSource().getInputStream()%>;

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the generated source from a browser like firefox (ctrl U) will see that your assigning a Java input stream to a java script object. That has no meaning. One way to solve your problem would be to read the input stream in Java (on your server) save that to a unique file name based on the audio src and then give a relative path to that file to the audio.src between double quotes.

First try the same from a static html file the relevant html will be something like

```
audio.src= "resources/audio/mysong.mp3";
```

will have to change mp3 to the correct extn depending on the type of format your getting from the web service.

To save the input stream you can search for how to save any input stream to a File (java.io.FileOutputStream)

also for repeated calls to the same audio you do not want to this, insted have a standard naming convention, first check if the file is created and saved (by the size maybe and some kind if cache) if its already there then just make the html (set the audio src without re saving the file)

There can be a number of issues if two people ask for the song at the same time, will have to use caching and a pause with possible some feedback to the user. Maybe a better way would be to render the page and then use ajax to ask the server for the URL, and tell the user on the page 'loading' via dynamic html. when the server has the url (after saving the file if required) it will respond and then the ajax powered javascript will set the audio.src and play the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that detailed answer but I already knew that it can be done that way. Isn't there any other way to read the InputStream without saving it to a file ?. I haven't found any yet

Comment: you can have a custom player in flash or java or write your own plugin.